# Increase performance of ASB reads/writes from Service Fabric application

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm looking to increase the throughput of a process (API Controller) that runs on Service Fabric. I have set the Service Fabric configuration to scale to the max number of instances configured in the Scale set. Let's say there are 10 instances of the API controller waiting for requests now. Every request is processed and sends a message to an ASB topic. What configuration is suggested (sessions, prefetch, etc.) so that each service can submit as many messages to the ASB Topic as possible?

Answer (score 0):

The guidance for this is well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#scenarios).

- To increase the overall send rate into the queue, use multiple message factories to create senders. For each sender, use asynchronous operations or multiple threads.
- Sessions negatively affect performance, as they guarantee order.
- Prefetch is for receivers only.
- Keep in mind the there are [rate limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-throttling).
- Using higher SKU's increases rate limits.
- Use the AMQP protocol
- Re-use the message sender object

Make sure to read the first link, as it contains more context.